Nginx otel module - how to use "otel_service_name name;"
How to configure the otel_service_name in the nginx.conf and in which section mentioned, not able to understand the documentation?
https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_otel_module.html
Syntax: otel_service_name name;
Default:
otel_service_name unknown_service:nginx;
Context:    http
Sets the “service.name” attribute of the OTel resource.
I am expecting sample configuration for nginx, how to define otel_service_name?
